# AsyncTask: invalidating view does not take effect

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-animation, android-view

**Update**

My small showcase is stored on Bitbucket

https://bitbucket.org/solvapps/animationtest

I have an Activity with a view in it. `Contentview` is set to this view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyView myView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
        startMovie();
    }

    public void startMovie(){
        MovieTask movieTask = new MovieTask(myView, this);
        movieTask.doInBackground(null);
    }

}
```

A MovieTask is an Asynctask and refreshes the view periodically.
But invalidate() doesn't refresh the view.

```
public class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    MyView drawingView;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MovieTask(MyView view, MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.drawingView =view;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        for(int i=20;i<100;i++){
            drawingView.myBall.goTo(i,i);
            publishProgress();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("DEBUG_DRAW","in  onProgressUpdate()");
                drawingView.invalidate();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: I am feeling stupid while writing this but can you please change `MovieTask movieTask = new MovieTask(myView, this);
        movieTask.doInBackground(null);` to `new MovieTask(myView, this).execute()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See how you are launching the `AsyncTask`:

```
    public void startMovie() {
        MovieTask movieTask = new MovieTask(myView, this);
        movieTask.doInBackground(null);
    }
```

You are manually calling a method inside some class called `MovieTask`, thus you are running a code on the same thread. Obviously, that is not your intention, you intended to run the computation code on a background thread.

Correct way to launch `AsyncTask` is using [`execute(Params...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)):

```
    public void startMovie() {
        MovieTask movieTask = new MovieTask(myView, this);
        movieTask.execute("");
    }
```

Now you will get the desired effect.

---

P.S.

Please, do not use that code: you do not need to launch a background thread in order to do that kind of stuff. As an alternative consider [Animators API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html).

Declare `setBall(int pos)` method inside `MyBall` class:

```
    public class MyView extends View {
        ...
        public void setBall(int pos) {
            myBall.setX(pos);
            myBall.setY(pos);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Then change `startMovie()` to following:

```
    public void startMovie() {
        // "ball" means, that Animators API will search for `public setBall(int)` method inside MyView.java and call that method
        ObjectAnimator ball = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myView, "ball", 20, 100);
        ball.setDuration(1000);
        ball.start();
    }
```

You'll get the same animation without a nasty code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are helpiung me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible case, first as described in [documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()):

> void invalidate () 
>   Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible,
>   onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the
>   future.

So try to run your code in `onResume`, there is a chance that `View` is not visible yet.

Secondly `View#invalidate` tells the system to redraw the view as soon as the main UI thread goes idle. That is, calling invalidate schedules your view to be redrawn after all other immediate work has finished.

If you'd like to have your view updated periodically use `Handler#postDelay` or run it in a separate thread and use `View#postInvalidate` to update the `View` and trigger the call to `onDraw`.